# GenericFileOpenError from Excel Graph API

Tags: excel, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We're using the .NET Microsoft Graph client library to read and write Excel spreadsheets in Office 365.

Since last Tuesday, we have been receiving `GenericFileOpenError` from the API whenever we attempt to open and read the used range of Excel spreadsheets in the Office 365 account of one particular user. All spreadsheets in this user's account are affected. When we uploaded and tested the same spreadsheets in our own Office 365 account, the problem did not reproduce. No other user is affected. The Http status code of the error is 500, indicating that the problem occurs in Excel online. Except for the status code and the error code `GenericFileOpenError`, no other information is included in the error response. Microsoft documentation does not provide any information about this error as well.

Here's the abridged version of the code that we use:

```
var sheetRequestBuilder = graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root
           .ItemWithPath(workbookRelativePath)
           .Workbook.Worksheets[worksheetName];

var request = sheetRequestBuilder.UsedRange().Request();

// This is where the error is thrown
WorkbookRange usedRange = request.GetAsync().Result;
```

We asked our user to contact Microsoft support, but they predictably directed the user back to us with the same error code and stack trace that we gave them in the first place.

At this point, we simply do not have enough information to investigate further, so any help or insight will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could somebody from the Excel or the Graph API team look into this please? More and more of our users are being affected by this. At the minimum, a simple acknowledgement that someone from Microsoft knows about this will still be much appreciated.